# How can I use the action extension to grab contents of webpage?

Tags: ios, swift, share-extension

I am trying to use an action extension in my iOS app to allow users to save a shopping item into a `UITableView`. I would like the share extension to work like this:

1. The user opens a webpage in Safari (eg. [this page](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/apple-iphone-xs-64gb-gold-verizon/6009862.p?skuId=6009862) on Best Buy)
2. The user taps the Share button and the Share Sheet appears.
3. The user can tap on my app icon and the `UIViewController` and the user should be able to tap done and the webpage details (product name and price) should get saved to my app.

However, I'm not sure how I can get some of the webpage content so I can get the item name and price.

I tried to use [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW12) on share extensions, however, it is written in Objective-C, not Swift.

I'm able to grab the webpage URL using the code below in the `didSelectPost()` method:

```
if let item = extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem {
    if let itemProvider = item.attachments?.first as? NSItemProvider {
        if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.url") {
            itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.url", options: nil, completionHandler: { (url, error) -> Void in
                if let shareURL = url as? NSURL {
                    print("Here is the URL: \(shareURL)")
                }
                self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler:nil)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the item name and item price from a website along with the URL when the user taps my app in the Safari share sheet?